# Issue in code while invoking selenium web driver method 'findElement' using java reflection api

Tags: java, reflection, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I tried with selenium web driver to get the WebElement using method **findElement**. it worked. but had the issue with reflection api, when i was trying to invoke the method **findElement** and argument as By.name("") to get WebElement in return. here the following lines can give more idea about issue.
**Javaw was throwing the exception that** 


> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName)
>     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)

---

*Tried in general Approach (Working)*

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Method[] methods = driver.getClass().getMethods();
for(Method method:methods){
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");
By by = By.name("email");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
```

*Implemented using Java reflection api (Exception occured through follwoing code)*

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Method[] methods = driver.getClass().getMethods();
for(Method method:methods){
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");
By by = By.name("email");
Class c = Class.forName(driver.getClass().getName());
Method getMethod = c.getMethod("findElement", new Class[]{by.getClass()});
getMethod.setAccessible(true);
WebElement element = (WebElement) getMethod.invoke(driver, by);
```

---

Please some one can guide to get work done of code using reflection api

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't use this:  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html  Reflection is difficult enough without using an interface when you will likely have three+ implementations eventually (for IE, FF, Chrome, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There really is no `findElement(By$name)` (`By.name` is a sublass of abstract `By`). Therefore, you must call either:

```
Method getMethod = c.getMethod("findElement", new Class[] { by.getClass().getSuperclass() });
```

or

```
Method getMethod = c.getMethod("findElement", new Class[] { By.class });
```

Additionally, the invocation of the method in your code is wrong, you need to change it to

```
WebElement element = (WebElement)getMethod.invoke(driver, by);
```

because the first argument is the object on which the method should be run.

Comment: And I'm sorry to pull it out, but the main question is _why?_ In usual code, there is almost never need for Reflection.

Comment: Here, i've given snippet of code to give the idea about issue. But, in Real context, I want to write the selenium wrapper class to call the method of abstarct class 'By' by giving the method name as argument. for me performance is not an issue.

Comment: @ChakradharKatta Yeah, that's what Reflection is for, I guess. Sounds interesting. Please, if you'll finish it and if it will be a public project, drop a link here afterwards ;).